# Convert a vector with rownames to a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample `vector` as below:

```
dput(single.SSE)
c(AASHTO.Ext.SSE = "13.1685678457711", AASHTO.Int.SSE = "2.57651416013485", 
Cai.Int.SSE = "4.78553017599823", Cai.Ext.SSE = "0.0683423975312745", 
Suks.Int.SSE = "4.45954027996822", Suks.Ext.SSE = "0.0338390012831625", 
Shahawy.Ext.SSE = "26.5084532366265", Henry.Int.SSE = "51.9309887392544", 
Henry.Ext.SSE = "26.80132330346", Rigid.Int.SSE = "0.766791166554609", 
Rigid.Ext.SSE = "3.81626934833545")
```

I want to convert this `vector` to a `data.frame` such that the `colnames` of the `data.frame` are the `rownames` of the existing vector and the first and only row of the `data.frame` is the values of the vector.

Comment: `data.frame(t(single.SSE))`

Comment: @maydin well that was just too simple.. thank you!

Comment: or you can use `single.SSE %>% enframe() %>% pivot_wider()` if youwant to use `tidyverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.data.frame.list`

```
out <- type.convert(as.data.frame.list(single.SSE), as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to matrix with `nrow = 1` and change the data to dataframe. Use `type.convert` to change the data to their respective types.

```
result <- type.convert(as.data.frame(matrix(single.SSE, nrow = 1, 
                       dimnames = list(NULL, names(single.SSE)))), as.is = TRUE)
```